# How to determine the last record in Mapper in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my mapper, I need to figure out whether a record is the last record given to this mapper or not. Is there any way to do that? That is, let's say a mapper is given 1000 records. The mapper process them one by one. How to figure out when the mapper is processing the last record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not possible inside `map()` method but you can save all input records and proceed them in `cleanup()` method.

Something like this:

```
public static class LastRecordMapper 
    extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private List<Map.Entry<Long, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Long, String>>();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
        data.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long, String>(key.get(), value.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Map.Entry<Long, String> lastRecord = data.get(data.size() - 1);

        /* ... Proceed last record ... */

    }

}
```

But be careful when keeping in RAM all input records because it may cause OutOfMemoryException if you have no enough heap size.

If you need only key and value of last input record then you can save only this one:

```
private Map.Entry<Long, String> lastRecord = null;

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
    lastRecord = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Long, String>(key.get(), value.toString());
}
```

Comment: @YoungHobbit I wrote about it at the end of the answer. Also you may require keep all input records if you want find not last record, for example.